# Why does Linq Group Join throw "NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor failed" exception?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to do a simple group join where my result set should be a List of `Doctors` who each have a List of `Patients`. It's also possible that a Doctor has no patients.

For some reason I'm getting the following exception when I run the query below.

```
Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<ApplicationUser>
    .GroupJoin(
        outer: DbSet<ApplicationUser>, 
        inner: doc => doc.Id, 
        outerKeySelector: p => p.DoctorId, 
        innerKeySelector: (doc, doc_patientsGroup) => new { 
            doc = doc, 
            doc_patientsGroup = doc_patientsGroup
         })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

```cs
                var q = from doc in _dbContext.Users
                        join p in _dbContext.Users on doc.Id equals p.DoctorId into doc_patientsGroup                        
                        join ur in _dbContext.UserRoles on doc.Id equals ur.UserId
                        join r in _dbContext.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                        where r.Name == Roles.DOCTOR
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = doc.Id,
                            UserName = doc.UserName,
                            Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", doc.FirstName, doc.LastName),

                            NumPatients = doc_patientsGroup.Count(), //<-- DOESN'T LIKE THIS
                        };

                var qq = await q.ToListAsync();

//model
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DoctorId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Doctor { get; set; }
        public List<ApplicationUser> Patients { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone explain how I should modify my query?
Thanks,

Comment: You could change it into a subquery, something like `NumPatients = _dbContext.Users.Count(p => p.DoctorId == doc.Id)`
Not the prettiest maybe, but they changed group joins in ef core 3+